# Tabularx environment and linespread

Tags: tabularx, line-spacing

I use the command `include{}` to import .tex files from other sources, and in one of them is used a `tabularx` environment. While my main/base .tex file, which is where the other .tex's are imported into, uses the command `linespread{2.0}` in its preamble, which functions with no doubt, only the lines in `tabularx` are unaffected. No matter where I add `\newcommand\linespread{2.0}` again, the lines in tabularx are kept in 1.0 linespread. How can I change the linespread in the `tabularx` into 2.0?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: it would be clearer if you provided an example `\include` isn't related to this and probably not `tabularx` either. Floats such as the `table` environment  call `\normalsize` which will reset the line spacing. Normally you should set `\baselinestretch` or use a package such as `setspace` rather than use `\linespread`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using David Carlisle's comment you get a line spacing of 2 with

- `\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}` for text
- `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{2}\selectfont` inside `table` environment

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \renewcommand\baselinestretch{2}\selectfont
    \caption{example table}
    \begin{tabularx}{10cm}{|X|X|}
        \hline
        foo & bar\\ \hline
        foobar & foo\\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]